# Syslog-ng log template \\011 character

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a problem with syslog-ng. I want to make syslog-ng to format the logs like below:

```
template("$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY\\011$HOUR:$MIN:$SEC\\011$HOST\\011$MSGHDR$MSGONLY\n")
```

But it logs without the "\". Just "011".
Example:

> Expected:  2012-11-28\\01116:33:51\\011host_name\\011app_name[26250]:
>   message
>
> Happened:  2012-11-2801116:33:51011host_name011app_name[26250]:
>   message

How to achieve this? Any ideas? :)
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

The template function appears to accept escaped characters, so you would need to add an extra `\` for each one:

```
template("$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY\\\\011$HOUR:$MIN:$SEC\\\\011$HOST\\\\011$MSGHDR$MSGONLY\n")
```